# Let $\phi: M \to N$ be an $R$-module homomorphism having a left-inverse $\psi$. Prove that $\ker (\psi) \cong \operatorname{coker} (\phi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\phi: M \to N$ be an $R$-module homomorphism having a left-inverse $\psi$.

I need to prove that $\ker ( \psi )\cong \operatorname{coker}  \phi $.

How to approach the problem? Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Verify that the sequence

$$0\longrightarrow \ker \phi\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}M\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}N\stackrel{(Id-\phi \circ \psi)|^{\ker \psi}}{\longrightarrow}\ker \psi ~ {\longrightarrow} ~0$$

is well-defined and exact.

---

Clarification:

The sequence

$$0\longrightarrow \ker \phi\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}M\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}N\stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow}\text{coker} \phi ~ {\longrightarrow} ~0$$

is clearly exact. It follows that $\text{coker} \phi \cong \ker \psi$. In general, if two sequences

$$0\longrightarrow A \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}B\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}C\stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow}D ~ {\longrightarrow} ~0$$
and 
$$0\longrightarrow A \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}B\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}C\stackrel{h'}{\longrightarrow}D' ~ {\longrightarrow} ~0$$
are exact, then $D \cong D'$. One can see this, for example, by defining the map $h(x) \mapsto h'(x)$. This is well defined, since $h$ is surjective and $h(x)=h(y) \implies x-y \in \ker h \implies x-y \in \text{Im}~ f \implies x-y \in \ker h' $
$\implies h'(x-y)=0 \implies h'(x)=h'(y).$ It is also a homomorphism, since $h$ and $h'$ are homomorphisms. And clearly it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Say, I will verify. But what does it gives us? Why $coker \ \phi = ker \ \psi$ if the sequence is exact? Could you, please, clarify?

Comment: @Jxt921 I've clarified. Please say if anything still isn't clear.

Comment: Can you please clarify how do I prove that $\ker \ (Id - \phi \ \psi)|^{\ker \psi} \subseteq im \ \phi$? That if, if $n = \phi( \psi (n))$, then $\exists n_1 \in N: \phi(n_1) = n$?

Comment: @Jxt921 If $n=\phi(\psi(n))$, $n$ is the image of $n_1=\psi(n)$ by $\phi$. Note that $n_1$ must be an element of $M$, not $N$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\operatorname{coker}\phi=N/\phi(M)$. Let's define a homomorphism $f\colon N\to N$ by
$$
f(x)=x-\phi\psi(x)
$$

1. Prove that $f(N)=\ker\psi$
2. Prove that $\ker f=\phi(M)$
3. Deduce that $\ker\psi=f(N)\cong N/\ker f=N/\phi(M)$.

Comment: I can't see anything new in this answer compared to the earlier one.

Comment: @user26857 Readers might not be acquainted with exact sequences. Besides, the map $\mathit{Id}-\phi\circ\psi$ has not the stated codomain, as written.

Comment: I didn't check the details of your answers, but you claim that $f(N)=\ker\psi$, and this is also what the other answer pointed out.

Comment: @user26857 This can confuse beginners: the instructor usually insists that maps have a well defined codomain and to keep image and codomain distinct; the codomain of $\mathit{Id}-\phi\circ\psi$ is $N$ by definition, not $\ker\psi$. The “corestriction” is a different map, speaking formally, although we're often sloppy and don't bother with these details; beginners do.

Comment: How can I prove that $ker f \subseteq \phi(M)$. Assume $n \notin \phi(M)$.  How do I deduce than then $n \neq \phi(\psi(n))$(that is, $f(n) \neq 0$)?

Comment: @Jxt921 Let $x\in\ker f$, that is, $x-\phi\psi(x)=0$; then $x=\phi\psi(x)\in\phi(M)$.

Comment: @egreg Of course! How did I miss it!? Thanks.